# Connector from Apache Cassandra to Ignite

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, ignite, connector

I am trying to build a connector from Apache Cassandra to Apache Ignite. Basically, I want to write all the new incoming data from Cassandra to Ignite. Is there any connector or something which can be helpful?

**N.B - Stream data from Cassandra to Ignite**

Comment: I'm not sure of that, but if there's it should be on Cassandra side. It's very non-trivial to listen on DB updates without help from said DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignite provides such integration out of the box, see here: https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/ignite-with-apache-cassandra

Comment: I want to stream data from Cassandra into Ignite. This article is about using Cassandra as a persistence store for Ignite.

Comment: If you want to take advantage of Ignite, it's better to use its API for all operations and have Cassandra (or any other persistence store) backing it via `CacheStore` implementation. That will provide best performance results with less effort. If it's not possible for some reason, the only way is to have some kind of a trigger on Cassandra side that would update Ignite explicitly (not sure if they provide such functionality).